# PHP Undefined index: admin in "filename" on line 48

Tags: php, mysql

I'm following the tutorial from [this site](http://css-tricks.com/php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/) and it won't stop giving me this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: admin in C:\Users\Feia\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 48.

Line 48 looks like this:

> echo ( $_GET['admin'] == 1 ) ? $obj->display_admin() : $obj->display_public();

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no &admin= in the URL

you should say

```
if(isset($_GET['admin'])){ //code here }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this code:

```php
echo (empty($_GET['admin'])) ? $obj->display_admin() : $obj->display_public();
```

Now, it works ;)